# How to filter a list with max value of an attribute using map-reduce in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list as follows:

```
let scores = [{name: "A", skills: 50, result: 80},
              {name: "B", skills: 40, result: 90},
              {name: "C", skills: 60, result: 60},
              {name: "D", skills: 60, result: 70}];
```

I want to filter the list who got max value in skills using **Map-Reduce** in typescript.

```
output = [{name: "C", skills: 60, result: 60},
          {name: "D", skills: 60, result: 70}];
```

I have tried as follows and got expected output:

```js
let scores = [{name: "A", skills: 50, result: 80},
              {name: "B", skills: 40, result: 90},
              {name: "C", skills: 60, result: 60},
              {name: "D", skills: 60, result: 70}];

let maxSkillValue = Math.max.apply(Math, scores.map(function (o) { return o.skills; }));
let output = scores.filter(i => i.skills === maxSkillValue);

console.log(output);
```

Looking for answers using **Map-Reduce**.

Comment: Why are you wanting a "one liner". What's the benefit? If you want single line code, remove your line breaks.

Comment: @ziggywiggy thanks for asking. Basically I am looking for map-reduce solution. Edited question and removed "one liner".

Comment: FYI, you can shorten your code with `let maxSkillValue = Math.max(...scores.map(o=>o.skills));` Aside from that, your approach is very clear and understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thanks @NinaScholz for the answer. How can I filter the first list if any object has max value in either "skills" or "result"? My expected output: output = [{ name: "B", skills: 40, result: 90 }, { name: "C", skills: 60, result: 60 }, { name: "D", skills: 60, result: 70 }] – ImtiazNur

```js
let scores = [{name: "A", skills: 500, result: 80},
              {name: "B", skills: 6000, result: 90},
              {name: "C", skills: 6000, result: 60},
              {name: "D", skills: 20, result: 60},
              {name: "E", skills: 10, result: 90}];

const maxSkill = scores.reduce((acc, curr) => curr.skills > acc ? curr.skills : acc, 0);
const maxResult = scores.reduce((acc, curr) => curr.result > acc ? curr.result : acc, 0);
const maxSkillsAndRes = scores.reduce((r, o) => (o.skills === maxSkill || o.result === maxResult) ? [...r,o] : r, []);

console.log(maxSkillsAndRes);
```

sry, about the third reduce line you'd better write :

```
const maxSkillsAndRes = scores.filter( o => o.skills === maxSkill || o.result === maxResult );
```

outputs are same but more readable

Comment: Thanks @Simon Dehaut for your answer. But it is pretty similar of mine as I also got the max value at first and filtered the list according to the max value. I need something using map-reduce.

Comment: do you mean a map and a reduce nested on the same line ?

Comment: it has no sense, if you write something like `.map(..reduce()...)` you apply  object on each element of `scores` array and if you write    `.reduce(...map()...)`  you select element of `scores` with an array returned by map() method

Comment: ok if you want really want to do this : https://jsfiddle.net/379ebtcg/ (my eg is dumb, not efficient, consume more mem and it's slower)`

`.map()` method is not designed for getting an array of (N +- x) elements based on an array of (N) elements

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Basically I needed this solution for research purpose, to compare complexity and execution time of an algorithm. Thanks for help.

Comment: ok nice, no problem. Send me a link of your work if you want. i'm interested :)

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the array by checking the result set or the last stored max skills value, then take this object as new result set in an array. Otherwis check if the skills is equal, then push the actual value and return the accumulator.

For getting the max objects from a certain count of properties, you could store the max values for each property and filter the part result set.

```js
let scores = [{ name: "A", skills: 50, result: 80 }, { name: "B", skills: 40, result: 90 }, { name: "C", skills: 60, result: 60 }, { name: "D", skills: 60, result: 70 }],
    maxSkills = scores.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r || r[0].skills < o.skills) return [o];
        if (r[0].skills === o.skills) r.push(o);
        return r;
    }, undefined),
    keys = ['skills', 'result'],
    max = scores.reduce((r, o) => {
        keys.forEach(k => r[k] = Math.max(k in r ? r[k] : -Infinity, o[k]));
        r._ = [...r._, o].filter(q => keys.some(k => r[k] === q[k]));
        return r;
    }, { _: [] })._;

console.log(maxSkills);
console.log(max);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz for the answer. How can I filter the first list if any object has max value in either "skills" or "result"? My expected output:

output = [{ name: "B", skills: 40, result: 90 }, { name: "C", skills: 60, result: 60 }, { name: "D", skills: 60, result: 70 }]